# flutter Remove background color from Floating Action Button

Tags: android, image, flutter, floating-action-button

I am using an image as a child of the floating action button on flutter. I don't need any background color.
and also I need to make the image size bigger. how can I do this? help, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
)
```

Comment: Wow its more owsum.  Wait Give you update.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** My answer is just a workaround. `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` goes well.

I think for your case, you can also try workaround like this,

```
floatingActionButton: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          // Do Something
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage("https://www.dartpad.dev/dart-192.png")),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.50),
          ),
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
```

Play with `height` and `width` values for desired result. You can also add `boxShadow` to `Container` to look like the actual FAB.

Refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html 
and also for including your image from asset, refer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/DecorationImage-class.html

Hope that suits your case!

Comment: Nice.  Will give you upadate after doing this.

Comment: its ok with network image, cannot add asset image?

Comment: You can use `AssetImage` too. Refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html

Answer (score 2):

```
Colors.transparent
```

Will remove the color from any widget which accepts color parameter. Please use it in your FloatingActionButton like below:

```
           FloatingActionButton(
              elevation: 0.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.check),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              onPressed: (){}
            )
```